# Can't access the fields of non-grouping tables in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I'm trying to join few tables using LINQ and retrieve a data set. But my problem is when I group the tables, I cannot access the fields of the non grouped tables in the LINQ query. here is my sample code block. Please help

```
var query = from sb in db.Surfboards
                    join csb in db.CustomerSurfBoards on sb.SurfBoardID equals csb.SurfBoardID
                    join c in db.Customers on csb.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                    where c.IsActive
                    group new { sb,csb} by new {sb.ID, csb.ComponentId} into g
                    select new ReportModel()
                    {
                        ReceivedDate = g.First().Name,
                        Number = c.First().Number <------- this cannot be accessed
                    }
```

what I'm trying to achieve is something like this

```
select sb.Id, max(c.Number), cbs.Id from Surfboards as sb
inner join CustomerSurfBoards as cbs on sb.SurfBoardID = csb.SurfBoardID
inner join Customers as c on csb.CustomerID =  c.CustomerID
group by sb.Id, csb.ComponentId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from sb in db.Surfboards
                    join csb in db.CustomerSurfBoards on sb.SurfBoardID equals csb.SurfBoardID
                    join c in db.Customers on csb.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                    where c.IsActive
                    select new {sb.id, c.number, cbs.componentid} into tmp
                    from t in tmp
                    group t by new {t.ID, t.ComponentId} into g
                    select new
                    {
                        g.Key.id, g.Key.componentid, number = g.Select(n=>n.number).OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault()
                    }
```